# Zend 1 3d party NameSpaces autoload don't working

Tags: php, zend-framework, amazon-web-services, namespaces, autoloader

I'm trying to implement Amazon WebServices PHP SDK into my Zend 1 project, but it seems to fail loading the classes.

I have got the library into `library/Eplan/AmazonCloudSearch` and after investigation it seems that in order to be able to load the namespace I need to call the `registerNamespace` method from `Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance()` so I've got this on the top of the autoloader (I also tried to put it in the bootstrap without luck):

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
$autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$autoloader->registerNamespace("Aws");
```

Namespaces of the AWS library are like this: `Aws\namespace`

The errors I get are like `Warning: include_once(Aws/Common/Aws.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /srv/www_nfs_desarrollo/vhosts/desarrollo.techmaker.net/httpdocs/library/Zend/Loader.php on line 134`

Autoloader full code: http://pastebin.com/gS9mcntK

I've been the full day struggling my head trying to solve this without luck, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use `$autoloader->registerNamespace('Aws')`, the AWS lib you seek must be on your PHP include path, which probably includes your `./library` directory. Instead, you have the AWS lib buried down in `./library/Eplan/AmazonCloudSearch`, which almost certainly is *not* on your PHP include_path.

Try moving the AWS library up two levels, directly into the `./library` directory.

Comment: You can also add the include path into your `application.ini` file with `includePaths.myPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/../wherever/it/may/be"`

Answer (score 1):

You can autoload using your application.ini file using following code.

**autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Aws"**